# Pass body value PATCH call

Tags: angular, http, service, request, patch

I have a problem on a PATCH call..
My code :

```
creerPwd(mail: string, token: string, password: string): Observable<void> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('tokenPassword', tokenPassword)
      .set('mail', mail);
    return this.http.patch(`/api/home/private/createPwd`,{ params: params }).pipe(
      map(() => { }),
    )
  }
```

I would like to switch to mail and token parameters => OK

But I would like to pass "password" in the body. How can I do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add a body as second parameter

```
this.http.patch(`/api/home/private/createPwd`, body, { params: params }
```

Comment: like this ? 
`
return this.http.patch(`/api/home/private/createPwd`, password, { params: params })`

Comment: an object with password in it { password }

Answer (score 0):

You can add body to the `HTTPClient.patch` request method by passing it in the second param.

```js
this.http.patch(url, body, params)
```

In your project:

```js
this.http.patch(url, { tokenPassword: tokenPassword }, { params: params })
```

You can also use the short syntax as the following:

```js
this.http.patch(url, { tokenPassword }, { params })
```

I also highly recommend using generic types on `HTTPClient` methods, like:

```js
this.http.patch<Response>(url, ...)
```

Response should be the type of the response you plan to receive back from the api.

Please read more on the [HTTPClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) in the official documentation.